# About Secure Connection Established?

Tags: php, security, ssl

I am running a Website which is SSL-secured. There is a form within an .html/.php on my Website/Server that shall address a .html/.php via $_POST on another SSL-secured Website/Server.

Is the connection from the User to the destination.php on the third party Website wholly secure?

Comment: If the form's action url is a HTTPS url, then the connection to the new website will be SSL-secured.

Comment: Nothing is "wholly secure", at least nothing humans have programmed. There are simply far too many factory involved to make such a statement. So the question is: what do you mean by that? https is the protocol between client and server, but php scripts are executed on the server, so that connection is irrelevant here. Only for the part between server and server, so the background connection, here an encryption does make sense, yes. But as said: there are many more factors to consider.